# FileWrite path on linux

Tags: java, filewriter

if i run this code nothing happens, not even catch exception.The string is not occur in the test.txt file.  The path of the test.txt file is ~ /home/joci/Joci. What I am dong wrong ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try{            
String text = "this is just a test ";

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/joci/Joci test.txt");
fw.write(text);
fw.close();

}catch(IOException e ){
System.out.println("Something went wrong ");

}
```

Comment: You forgot to indent your code. It's not the source of your problem, but it's something you're doing wrong.

Comment: A space in the path or checking the wrong location: `~ /home/joci/Joci` you sure of this? Did you put a home folder inside your home?

Comment: is this the file name? Joci test.txt

Comment: Is your filename `test.txt` or `Joci test.txt` ?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna if a write with ~/home/joci/Joci then the catch executes. 
if you asking that  test.txt is in Joci repo then yes!

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna sorry i maent direktory not repo.

Comment: @khelwood test.txt

Comment: The file `test.txt` in the folder `/home/joci/Joci` would have the path `/home/joci/Joci/test.txt` , not `/home/joci/Joci test.txt` . Even assuming that `/home/joci/Joci` is the correct absolute path to your folder.

Comment: @khelwood it works thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I your problem is that

```
"/home/joci/Joci test.txt"
```

does **not** denote a valid file name under Linux; so you simply drop that space; or replace it with _ or - for example. Or use `\\` to escape that space.

But I just tried:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  try{            
    String text = "this is just a test ";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/myhome/tmp/out 21.txt");
    fw.write(text);
    fw.close();
  }catch(IOException e ){
  System.out.println("Something went wrong ");
  }  
}
```

}

And that just *worked* fine. So there must be something else in your setup that causes this problem!

Besides: the `~` character is a functionality of the **shell** of your Linux. The JVM does not know that this character means "home"; thus you should simply **not at all** use it within your java source code!

Comment: but it does not work i tried with all _ - \ 
if i write with these the catch does not execute and i dont see the string in the file

Comment: Final hint: such discussions we have here ... will distract future readers. That is why will go in now and delete all my comments ... if you want to, just do the same (using the little x icon that pops up close to your comment when mousing over it)

Comment: how can we keep in touch ? do you want to ? )

Comment: Well, you can just bookmark my profile and check out my activities here. You are always welcome to drop a comment on content of mine; and when I am around I will sure look by. If you have any specific ideas, needs, requests ... let me know ... would be my first SO mentoring I guess ;-)